# Android studio background img

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

What is the best way to put img as background? I try `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`. As a first child add an `ImageView` with:

```
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
or
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
or
```

but both don't work (I want to have full-screen background). I load img from drawable by

```
android:background="@drawable/menumain
```

(in Imageview)

Comment: Maybe you should use android:src instead of android:background.

Comment: Need same background image for all layouts?

Comment: @Ov3r1oad I used android:src (in imageview) instead of background and android:scaleType="fitXY" but there is the same problem (there is not full screen, actually main layout is RelativeLayout)

Comment: @salihkallai i want put one background image (in main layout)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no need to use an Image View, just use the `android:background` attribute of the main layout of the view, (which I assume should be filling the screen)

Comment: Yeah, this should work perfectly. Saves the trouble of loading another widget.

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work (there is not full screen)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a style.xml in values folder and add a style to it.

```
<style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

put your background image in drawable(splash_screen)
Second, in your app Manifest.xml add android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" to your main activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" >
```

NOTE:This code is actually for setting splashscreen but you can also use it for set background image

Answer (score 0):

then use `android:background="@drawable/img_name"` in your content_main.xml inside Relative Layout TAG.I have assumed that you are talking about activity's background.